# SockJS using invalid URL for WebSockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, sockjs

Using both the 0.3 and development versions of SockJS, I have tried to run the echo server/client demos, and on the client it falls back to XHR streaming with the following error in the console:

```
Wrong url scheme for WebSocket http://localhost:9999/ws/014/ti0jz5iw/websocket
```

Where it should probably be using a ws:// schema.

On the client, I'm connecting with:

```
var sock = new SockJS('echo');
```

and the server is the [sockjs-node echo server](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/blob/master/examples/echo/server.js) demo.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Just a comment. I recommand using [socket.io](http://socket.io/) since this is much easier to understand.

Comment: @Bondye Unfortunately I can't install Socket.IO without Visual Studio, so that won't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. For some reason using the URL `http://localhost:9999/echo` works fine now.